# Does .html extension in URL help for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

I am working on `dotNET` and I have changed `URL` extension from `.aspx` to `.html`. Is it good to use .html extension ?
My actual URL is `www.example.com/Project.aspx?Id=2&Type=this-is-something`
I have replace this as `www.example.com/Projects/2/this-is-something`
Is it fine ? Else give me suggestion which `URL` should I use for `SEO`. I can make URL anyhow I want using URL Rewriting.
I want to make it best URL for SEO. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is easy. Option 2. What? You want more? Okay. If you insist!

In your first example, and outside of the domain name, the only thing that would really count for keywords in that URL/URI is the parameter (after the &).

In your second example, the entire URL/URI counts for keywords. It is more effective/efficient.

However, using parameters can be just as effective/efficient. My site uses a single one character parameter which is an alias that returns a page. No, as in your example, Project.aspx. Just a single parameter and that works just peachy keen. It is not a folders verses parameters thing where one is better than the other. That was an argument like a thousand years ago that no longer applies as search engine spiders began to parse URL/URI(s) more effectively. It is the URL/URI combination and how cleanly does it present your keywords and page topics. This can be evaluated by simply looking at the URL/URI. Is it more sentence than cryptic?

Comment: Right now, my url is `www.example.com/Projects/2/this-is-something.html`. So should I use that one this one `www.example.com/Projects/2/this-is-something` ???

Comment: Am I missing something? These look the same to me.

Comment: yeah, u said everything clearly. But, I want to know does .html matter in url ? or without .html will be better.

Comment: Oh. I guess I shoulda put my glasses on! It actually does not matter. Some argue that search engines favor actual HTML pages, but that was a long time ago. Today, it does not matter. After all, what is returned in HTTP response packets look the same either way and that is what matters along with presenting parsable keywords in clean URL/URI(s).

Comment: While we are on the topic, there is one thing that remains to be true. Keywords are still evaluated and weighted from left to right. This is because our brains, for most of us, have been trained to think this way and importance ordering is something we do naturally. There is some semantic shifting of keyword weight, but if you pay attention to how you use your keywords from left to right, that may help you perform better in the SERP(s). But still do not sweat it too much.

Comment: Anytime! I am usually here late at night if that helps. Most people have gone to bed, but I am writing code and doing database work almost every night.

Comment: that's cool. I just reached at office, I am dotNET & android developer.

Comment: I am semi-retired and run a couple of businesses during the daytime and do security research at night.

Comment: nice. I am looking for out sourcing work, let me know if u can help me.

Comment: I mostly do automation process analysis for security based systems for defense and infrastructure such as gas, oil, water, electric, and so on. I do some things extremely well, but I mostly do not do web stuff except for the basic. I do know search engines very well because of some search engine seeding, filters, and data mining I used to do. I was also an OS internal coder back in the day. I know stuff, but have not kept up with the latest greatest web code.